# SAS - proc sql for table update in a macro

Tags: sas

I have a code that tries to update a table in a macro block using macro variables in a sub-query. The challenge I have is that at times some of the macro variables are null, thus making the code fail. How can I set it to ignore when the macro varible produces a null value?

```
    %macro update_bucket;
%let macro_fudge = %nrstr(%mend);

proc sql;
%do i=1 %to &rows.; 
    %do j=1 %to &max_comb.; 
        %do k=1 %to &max_LGD_comb.; 
            %do l=1 %to &max_PD_comb.;  

                %let x = _&&k.LGD&i.;   
                %let y = _&&l.PD&i.;    

                    %if &x. ^=LTV %then %do; 

                        update sbbook_rb_A as a
                        set riskbucket = (select risk_bucket from PORTFOLIO_SPLIT_D as b
                                where a.businessgroup = b.portfolio
                                and a.product2 = b._&j.subport
                                and a.&&&x. >= b.min_lgd_driver_%left(&k.) /* at times "a.&&&x." returns a null value */ 
                                and a.&&&x. < b.max_lgd_driver_%left(&k.)
                                and a.&&&y. >= b.min_pd_driver_%left(&l.) /* at times "a.&&&y." returns a null value */ 

                                and a.&&&y. < b.max_pd_driver_%left(&l.) 
                                            and b.row_num = &i.
                                )
                        where riskbucket = '';
                    %end;
            %end;
        %end;
    %end;
%end;
quit;
%mend;
%update_bucket;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Best practice in most cases like this is to use parameters, not global macro variables.  In that case you can give them a default value, which you can then test for and skip the loop (for example, you could give a default value of 0).

```
%macro mymacro(param1=0, param2=0);

...
%mend mymacro;
```

You should *never* rely on globals the way you did in that code, regardless of this; any macro variable that is used in the macro should be a parameter to the macro, excepting very clearly global things like paths (and even then, I prefer those to be parameters).  You can pass a global as the value to the parameter, but it should be clearly passed.

Comment: Interestingly, in this case there is no need for tests with a default value of 0 as `%do i = 1 %to 0;` will not run the loop contents without a negative `%by` value. Then again, it never hurts to learn good habits.

Comment: I'm struggling a little bit to figure out how that would help solve my challenge. The macro variables in my sub-query (i.e. a.&&&x and a.&&&y) could either be blank or both be blank at the same time, and I still want the code to run whenever this occurs wthout generating an error. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the ways to test if a macro var is empty:

```
%If &&&x=  %then
%If &&&x=%str() %then
%If %length(&&&x)=0 %then
```

In your example, to prevent an error, it would seem you could do the following (don't forget the trailing semicolon for your %If %Then statement):

```
%If &&&x^=%str() %then and a.&&&x >= b.min_lgd_driver_&k;
```

A couple more suggestions:

- There is no need for a trailing period after a macro variable if what
  immediately follows is a space or a semicolon.
- There is no need for the %left() macro function around your macro var
  counters...they are created without leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: I would extend your statement about no need for a trailing period to say "if what immediately follows isn't an underscore, character, or numeric digit" (ie. the values allowed for use in a macro variable name).  Personally I find that unnecessary underscores make the code more difficult to read.

Comment: Also, the way I (normally) test to see if a macro variable is empty is to put some bookends around it.  You can use almost any character, I normally just use double quotes as people are used to seeing macro variables within double quotes. ie.  `%if "&x" eq "" %then %do` but you could also use the `#` symbol or whatever else works for you.  The beauty of this is you can put the expression into a %put statement for easy debugging. e.g. %put `"&x" eq ""`.  If you end up with an empty string or a space, it clearly will show that they are not equal.  I do this for testing equality of macro vars too